# Client unable to read respose from API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I created

1. Web api
2. Client.

I am trying to make a simple get request from client to Api
When I debug I can see that my client sends request to web api, web api receives it fine and returns a response. But seems like the response never reaches my client and client keeps waiting forever.

I tried using Postman tool to my Web api and received response fine in json form

I also tried using Fiddle to see where things are going wrong. It showed a downward arrow indicating that the Response was being read from the server. It did not show any error code.

Can someone please suggest what I could be doing wrong.

API:

```
// GET: api/Account
public IEnumerable<Account> Get()
{
    //return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
      Account a = new Account(100, "RES", new Customer(1, "K", "M"), new Premise(1, "2225", "City A", "Ohio"));
      Account a1 = new Account(101, "RES", new Customer(1, "R", "M"), new Premise(1, "Prior Road", "Texas", "US"));
      Account a2 = new Account(102, "RES", new Customer(1, "A", "M"), new Premise(1, "estern Road", "NY", "US"));
      List<Account> list = new List<Account>();
      list.Add(a);
      list.Add(a1);
      list.Add(a2);
      return (list);
}
```

CLIENT :

```
public async Task<List<Account>> SelectAllAccounts()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:62617/api/");
        //HTTP GET
        var response = await client.GetAsync("Account");

        var myInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        List<Account> a= null;
        a.Add(myInstance);
        return a;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some typos exist in your simple example, which should be modified:

```
  // GET: api/Account
        public List<Account> Get()
        {
              Account a = new Account(100, "RES", new Customer(1, "K", "M"), new Premise(1, "2225", "City A", "Ohio"));
              // ... 
              // ... Your Code here
              // ... 
              list.Add(a2);
              return list;            
        }
```

And, you also need to modify your Client-Side:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62617/");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Account").Result;

            string _content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            List<Account> myInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Account>>(_content);


            return myInstance;
        }
```

You can `return myInstance` or return `View(myInstance)`, or return it as **JsonResult**, whichever suits your need. For instance:

```
return Json(new { Status = 200, LIST = myInstance}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

However, sometimes it may be better to return `_content` as `string` and let De-serialization be done for the last moment.

For more info, following are simple Nice examples on how to create and consume Rest APIs in ASP.Net MVC framework:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-simple-web-api-in-asp-net-mvc/
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-asp-net-web-api-rest-service-in-asp-net-mvc-using-http-client/
- https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consume-web-api-get-method-in-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning IEnumerable I suggest return HttpResponseMessage and also set ContentType to application/json.
So your api will be like this,

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = this.Request.CreateResponse<List<Account>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, list);
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
return httpResponseMessage;
```

In Client code you have to deserialize to List as you are returning collection instead of just Account. So changes in Client code will be

```
 var myInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Account>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

It's tried and tested. 
:-)